Evaluating $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{(1+\sqrt{1})(1+\sqrt{2}) \cdots(1+\sqrt{n})}$
What is this limit?
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{(1+\sqrt{1})(1+\sqrt{2}) \cdots(1+\sqrt{n})}$$
I've tried to squeeze the function and got a lower bound of zero, but can't get an useful upper bound. Also can't convert this into a definite integral.

Hint:$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\cdots\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Thank you. Didn’t see this.

Observe that
$$\frac{\sqrt{n!}}{(1+\sqrt 1)(1+\sqrt 2)\cdots (1+\sqrt{n})}=\frac1{\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt1}\right)\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\cdots \left(1+\frac1{\sqrt {n}}\right)}$$
and as pointed out in the comments
$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\cdots\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow{n\to \infty} \infty$$
and hence the required limit is $0$.

Probably too advanced then, at least, for your curiosity since you received the good tricks for the limit.
Consider
$$a_n=\frac{\sqrt{n!}}{\prod _{k=1}^n  \left(1+\sqrt{k}\right)}$$ Take logarithms
$$\log(a_n)=\frac 12\log(n!)-\sum _{k=1}^n \log\left(1+\sqrt{k}\right)$$
Considering at least the continuous case
$$\sum _{k=1}^n \log\left(1+\sqrt{k}\right)\sim \int _{1}^n \log\left(1+\sqrt{k}\right)$$
$$\int _{1}^n \log\left(1+\sqrt{k}\right)\,dk=(n-1) \log
   \left(\sqrt{n}+1\right)-\frac{1}{2}   \left(\sqrt{n}-1\right)^2$$
Using Stirling approximation
$$\frac 12\log(n!)-\int _{1}^n \log\left(1+\sqrt{k}\right)\,dk=-2\sqrt n+\frac 34 \log(n)+ \left(1+\frac{1}{4} \log (2 \pi
   )\right)+\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{n}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ Exponentiate
$$ a_n \sim \exp\Bigg(-2\sqrt n+\frac 34 \log(n)+\left(1+\frac{1}{4} \log (2 \pi
   )\right)+\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{n}}  +O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\Bigg)\tag 1$$
We could do better using the simplest form of Euler-MacLaurin summation and obtain
$$a_n \sim \exp\Bigg(-2\sqrt n+\frac 12 \log(n)+C+\frac{1}{6 \sqrt{n}}  +O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\Bigg)$$
For this level of summation
$$C=\frac{21065689}{20643840}+\frac{1}{4} \log \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\tag 2$$
For $n=100$, $(1)$ gives $a_{100}=\color{red}{6.509}50\times 10^{-8}$.
Just by curiosity, look how different are the coefficients in $(1)$ and $(2)$ (beside the very first one).

Too advanced indeed, but precise (+).

Raising to the second power gives $${n!\over (1+\sqrt{1})^2(1+\sqrt{2})^2\ldots (1+\sqrt{n})^2}\\ \le {n!\over (1+1)(2+1)\ldots (n+1)}={1\over n+1}$$ Thus the sequence in question is bounded above by ${1\over \sqrt{n+1}}.$
Remark The estimate can be slightly improved by observing that $(1+\sqrt{k})^2\ge k+3.$ Hence
$${n!\over (1+\sqrt{1})^2(1+\sqrt{2})^2\ldots (1+\sqrt{n})^2}\\ \le {n!\over (1+3)(2+3)\ldots (n+3)}={6\over (n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$ Hence the sequence can be estimated above by ${\sqrt{6}\over n\sqrt{n}}.$
A precise estimate is provided in the answer of @Claude Leibovici  basing roughly on $\log(1+x)\approx x$ for $x\to 0^+.$
